# Golang net.Conn Write in parallel

Tags: go, network-programming

I have multiple Goroutines sharing a net.Conn object. Can they issue a Write calls simultaneously?

My main concern is that of Write calls which are partially done. Say I intend to wrote 100 bytes, but only 30 were sent, so I need to send 70 more. For this I will typically write a loop:

```
count := 0
for count < len(buf) {
    byteSent, err := conn.Write(buf[count:])
    //check error 

    count += byteSent
}
```

But I see that Go implements this loop in [net.Conn.Write](https://golang.org/src/net/fd_unix.go) line number 318 and it does so by taking a lock.

However, on [Windows](https://golang.org/src/net/fd_windows.go) implementation there is no such loop except that there is a call to WSASend. I do not know how WSASend behaves and could not get much from the MSDN docs

Hence the questions are:

[edit] Added 4th question

1. Do I need to acquire a lock everytime I write to socket?
2. If yes, then the purpose of acquiring the lock in Write implementation is defeated.
3. In unix implementation, does it mean that I cannot get byteSent < len(buf) unless err != nil? (I mean am I reading the code correct?)
4. Does the WSASend on Windows implements the equivalent loop in Unix implementation

Comment: The documentation states: "Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.". If that doesn't hold true for all platforms then it's a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: You right. The only thing stopping me to file the bug is that I do not know whether WSASend implements the loop equivalent to unix impl or not. Hence the question on SO

Comment: Normally you file a bug when you have proof that it doesn't work correctly. Otherwise you assume the code works as advertised.

Comment: I just found out that there is no looping required for WSASend [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752103/how-to-make-sure-that-wsasend-will-send-the-data). This answers my questions. I will check some more, else I will answer this myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [io.Write](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) says that in case of partial write, err will be != nil
2. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752103/how-to-make-sure-that-wsasend-will-send-the-data) on StackOverflow that WSASend need not have a loop around it.
3. From #1 & #2, it implies that I need not acquire lock before calling net.Conn.Write.

So my question stands answered.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can make many calls to a `net.Conn`'s write method in parallel.

Part of `net.Conn`'s contract is that it can be used from multiple Goroutines concurrently. This is explicitly called out in [its documentation](https://godoc.org/net#Conn):

> Conn is a generic stream-oriented network connection.
>
> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

Though I can't speak to the Windows implementation in particular, this statement holds true for all platforms. Since there is no loop in the Windows implementation then `WSASend` calls must make guarantees that the Unix API does not.